# How to use plus character in regex

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

I have written a snippet, but it doesn't work correctly.

I have an input in this format:

```
Arg2+res=(s11_19,s11_20,s11_21,s11_22),Arg4-res=()
```

It can contain multiple Args (e.g. Arg1, Arg2, ...).
What I want, is to return `+res`instances. For example, in the above example, I need this part:

```
Arg2+res=(s11_19,s11_20,s11_21,s11_22)
```

My Regex is like the following:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Arg\\d+\\+res=\\(\\S+\\)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(ove_imp_roles);
    while (m.find()) {

        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

The code has two problems:

1) It returns the whole string as a single match. For example, in the above sentence it returns `Arg2+res=(s11_19,s11_20,s11_21,s11_22),Arg4-res=()` as the matching instance.

Even if both instances include `Arg1+res`, it returns the whole string as a single match, while I expect it to be returned as two different matches.

2) The code counts instances with `-res`, too, while I don't need them.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Update: I checked the code again and updated the above question correspondingly. The problem with `-res` occurs when it includes empty brackets (for example `Arg1-res=()`.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your pattern works for me. Note that you are iterating `find`, then printing `find` again instead of `group`, so your only outcome here will be `false`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake in writing the question. I corrected that. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `(\\S+\\)`. If you have the following input:

```
String s = "Arg2+res=(s1355_19,s1355_20);Arg3-res=(s1355_19,s1355_20)";
```

`Arg\\d+\\+res=\\(` matches `Arg2+res=(` and then `S+` will match (because the `+` is greedy):

```
s1355_19,s1355_20);Arg3-res=(s1355_19,s1355_20
```

So you can make it lazy, so that it stops as soon as it finds the first right parenthesis in the input:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Arg\\d+\\+res=\\(\\S+?\\)");
```

Alternatively, you can split the input by `';'` and see if each String matches `"^Arg\\d+\\+.*$"`

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `m.find()` inside `while(m.find())`, make it like this:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Arg\\d+\\+res=\\(\\S+\\)");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(ove_imp_roles);
 while (m.find()) {
     System.out.println(m.group());
 }
```

[btw your regex is matching 2nd `Arg` correctly](https://regex101.com/r/cQ5uD1/1)

---

Based on the **edited** question and new input OP can use this regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Arg\\d+\\+res=\\([^)]+\\)");
```

`[^)]+` will match 1 or more characters that are not `)`.

Comment: That's a bit strange. It doesn't work when it's in my java code. I exactly copy this code, but it returns the whole string as the output.
Also, if you try this input: 
Arg2+res=(s3_63,s3_64),Arg4+res=(s3_26,s3_27,s3_28,s3_29,s3_30,s3_31)
you can see that (even in the online tester), the whole string is returned as the answer. I wan the two parts separately.

Comment: Can you show your full code in question because regex is working fine as you can see in rege101 demo

Comment: Just checked your updated question. You can use: `Arg\\d+\\+res=\\([^)]*\\)`